# Performance Penalty for Finalizer If Never Called

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, finalizer

I have a class with a finalizer.  But since I'm always calling `Dispose()` and `Dispose()` is calling `GC.SupressFinalize(this)`, I think my object never actually makes it into the finalization queue.  The finalizer is just in there as a backstop in case another user of the class forgets to call `Dispose()`.

Is there any performance penalty for just implementing a finalizer even if its never called and the object never makes it to the finalization queue?

I used to think not, but on page 102 of *Effective C#: Second Edition* by Bill Wagner, it says, "Even if it's never called, the presence of a finalizer does introduce a rather large performance penalty for your types."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any performance penalty for just implementing a finalizer even if its never called and the object never makes it to the finalization queue?

As long as you implement this correctly, and call `GC.SuppressFinalize` on your object, the "penalty" will only occur when the user does not call `Dispose()`.

That being said, the "severe" penalty is actually not all that severe in most cases.  It would be a problem if you had many short lived objects with finalizers polluting your garbage collection process, but that's rarely a problem, since objects with finalizers are rare (overall).

Comment: Even if objects with Finalizers are rare, you could potentially not GC a _lot_ of objects, based on the references held...

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the problem with finalizers is that objects with them survive for an extra gc cycle. This only applies if the finalizer is called, however. This article explains it well: http://anasoft.wordpress.com/2007/06/17/more-about-gc-dispose-and-finalize/